# Not Found The requested URL when user exists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, .htaccess

I have a button "Add to Favourites", which once clicked, should store details (on the database) of who sent the favourites request and to whom it was sent to.

However, with all the functional code (which I expect should work), when I click on the "Add to Favourites" button, I am getting the message:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /www/profile.php was not found on this server.
```

`profile.php` works perfectly, but the error arises when the button is clicked. Additionally, when the button is clicked, the url says `http://localhost/Freddy` (Freddy is the username of the user logged in). This leads me to believe in the implementation of `$user_u_var` (see code below) - but I just cannot wrap my head around it.

**Button**:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $username; ?>" method="post"> 
     <input type="submit" class="send_message" name="sendmsg" value="Send Message"/>
     <input type="submit" class="add_to_fav" name="addfriend" value="Add to Favourites"/>
 /form>
```

**Code which is executed on button click:**

```
<?php
// code to process a favourite request
if (isset($_POST['addfriend'])){ // vars
    $fav_request = $_POST['addfriend'];
    $request_sent_to = $user_u_var; 
    $request_sent_from = $username;

    if ($request_sent_to == $user_u_var){
        echo "cannot send request to self";
    }

} else {
  //do nothing                  
    }
?>
```

**The origin of $user_u_var**

```
if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $user_u_var = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_GET['u']);
    if (ctype_alnum($user_u_var)) { //check if the user exists
    $check = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT username, first_name FROM users WHERE username='$user_u_var'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check)===1) {
        $get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
        $user_u_var = $get['username'];
        $fname = $get['first_name'];    
    } else { // refresh page 
        // if the user doesnt exist i.e. ?u=fakeUser - it will redirect them to the index page.
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://localhost/index.php\">"; 
        exit();
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Of course, as I am trying to send myself a favourite request, it should echo `cannot send request to self` but it simply renders an error.

**The origin of $username (session variable):**

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!isset ($_SESSION["user_login"])){      
    header("Location:index.php");
} else {
    $username = $_SESSION["user_login"];
}
?>
```

I have also added a .HTACCESS file to make the URL look better, which I may contribute to this error.

**.HTACCESS**

```
RewriteBase /www/
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1
```

I.e. assume I am on the index page: `localhost/index.php`. I want to go directly to Alice's profile page, so instead of writing `localhost/index.php?u=Alice`, using the RewriteRule's I can simply write `localhost/index.php/Alice`.

**Question**:
Why am I getting redirected to a "Not Found" page when clicking on the "Add to Favourites" button?

Comment: when you click the button to which link is it requesting ?

Comment: are both files in the same folder in www? Post your whole form as well

Comment: @Juakali92 Both files as in profile.php & .HTACCESS? In which case yes. Both files are present in the www folder (Wamp > www > where all my web pages can be found as well as .htaccess).

Comment: @яша - When the button is clicked it will eventually send data to the database (Which is not implemented yet). At the moment, the code in the if statement isn't working so I haven't proceeded to implement the sending data to database stuff yet.